# How do I add a bucket name to s3.Bucket in aws cdk

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I can create an aws cdk s3.CfnBucket with a "bucket_name" argument and it looks good. Does the "s3.Bucket" cdn construct have a bucketName property? It is documented as a cdk.PhysicalName property, but, I can't figure out how to construct a new PhysicalName.

Comment: bucket_name="". My next question is: "how do I delete my question?".

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends a bit on the CDK version you are using. Imho with version 0.35.0 it changed to the usage of the PhysicalName.

```
const srcBucket = new Bucket(this, "ImageResizeSourceBucket", {
  bucketName: PhysicalName.of("de.freitag.stefan.imageresize")
});
```

Comment: In `0.36` it rolled back to `string` again.